# Problem connecting buttons to a function (PyQT5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm new to Python 3.8 and PyQT5 and I'm trying to make an application with a GUI.

I've created a login form with two QLineEdits (User and Password). I want to check if what the user entered as User/Password is in a database using a function that it's in other file once the user clicks the 'Login' button. The class I've created for the form is similar to the next one:

```
# Where the check function for the password is
from CLBK_CheckPassword import CheckPassword
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class W_Password(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, App):
    
        super(W_Password,self).__init__()
    
        # Set the window title and size
        WindowHeight = 400
        WindowWeight = WindowHeight/3
        self.setWindowTitle("Login Window")
        self.resize(WindowHeight,WindowWeight)
    
        # Text box
        self.Input_User = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.Input_Password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.Input_Password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)

        # Button
        self.Button_Login = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Login")
        self.Button_Login.clicked.connect(CheckPassword())

        # Layout and items positioning
        self.Layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.Button_Login,3,2,1,2)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.Label_User,0,0,1,1)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.Input_User,0,1,1,3)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.Label_Password,1,0,1,1)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.Input_Password,1,1,1,3)
```

I have two problems with this code:

1. When the form is created and shown, the function 'CheckPassword()' is automatically executed (it should be only executed if the user press the button).
2. The second problem is that I've the following error once the function has been executed : *TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem 1

You should pass the `CheckPassword` function as a parameter to event listener `clicked.connect`.

So

```
self.Button_Login.clicked.connect(CheckPassword())
```

line changes to:

```
self.Button_Login.clicked.connect(CheckPassword)
```

### Problem 2

Your function `CheckPassword` seems to takes at least one parameter. So you have to change logic a little bit.

You can use `lambda` expression:

```
self.Button_Login.clicked.connect(lambda: (CheckPassword(THE_PARAMETER)))
```

### Edit

Answer to:  what if the function 'CheckPassword' returns something?

As [musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante) mentioned you can have another method which would run your function and capture the return value like:

```
# Where the check function for the password is
from CLBK_CheckPassword import CheckPassword
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class W_Password(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, App):
    
        super(W_Password,self).__init__()
    
        ...
        self.Button_Login.clicked.connect(lambda: (self.checher()))

        ...

    def checher(self):
        value = CheckPassword(THE_PARAMETER)
        # Do something with value
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly ! I've another question that comes to my mind: what if the function 'CheckPassword' returns something ? Is it possible to save it in a variable ?

Comment: @Ralk the return value of connected functions is always ignored. Create another method for W_Password and connect it to the clicked signal, then you can create a reference for the returned value as an instance attribute.